# Azure Pipeline CLI run pipeline for branches

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm working on something where I need there to be a few build jobs queued on Azure DevOps pipelines.

I have a dummy repo and eight branches. I was trying to trigger the pipeline to build them all via CLI/script rather than having to click through the UI each time

I tried this

```
#!/bin/bash

typeset -a branches
branches[1]="BRANCH-001"
branches[2]="BRANCH-002"
branches[3]="BRANCH-003"
branches[4]="BRANCH-004"
branches[5]="BRANCH-005"
branches[6]="BRANCH-006"
branches[7]="BRANCH-007"
branches[8]="BRANCH-008"

for branch in ${branches[*]}
do
  az pipelines run --branch $branch --name $branch
done
```

And it throws out this

```
The Azure DevOps Extension for the Azure CLI does not support Azure DevOps Server.
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? I just want to be able to kick off a small number of builds so I can iterate over 'inProgress' and 'notstarted' builds.

Appreciate any insight anyone might have.

Many thanks

_scott

Answer (score 0):

My bad

Correct code should be as below

--name should be name of ADO project
--branch should be /refs/heads/$branch

```
typeset -a branches
branches[1]="BRANCH-001"
branches[2]="BRANCH-002"
branches[3]="BRANCH-003"
branches[4]="BRANCH-004"
branches[5]="BRANCH-005"
branches[6]="BRANCH-006"
branches[7]="BRANCH-007"
branches[8]="BRANCH-008"

project='skeet'

for branch in ${branches[*]}
do
  echo $branch
  az pipelines run --name $project --branch=refs/heads/$branch
done
```

It also looks like I had some old ADO config somewhere pointing to a bad/old ADO org

Had to clear/correct it with

```
az devops configure --defaults organization=https://dev.azure.com/$org project=$project
```

After that `az devops cli` started to behave as expected

Thanks